# how to determine whether a function can sleep or not?

Tags: linux, sleep, interrupt-handling, routines

In the Linux, interrupt handler which also called top half cannot sleep.

The issue is that **How can I determine whether a function can cause sleep?**

Can I use `input_event`, `input_sync` in top half?

Answer (score 0):

**How can I determine whether a function can cause sleep?**

If any IO-bound operation is done, it may sleep. but I doubt any specific tool which finds whether it will sleep or not.

**Can I use input_event, input_sync in top half?** 
I got linux documentation which uses input_sync  in top half.  http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/input/input-programming.txt?id=HEAD